# mongoose populate match condition on nested of nested

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

It's my **Mongoose** find query:

```
this.model.System.find({}, {
    _id: 0,
})
    .populate(
        {
            path: "subsystems",
            populate: {
                path: "sections",
                populate: {
                    path: "allowedUsers.user",
                    model: "User",
                },
            },
        }
    )
    .exec((error, systems) => {
       /////// 
    });
```

And it's a sample result:

```
[
    {
        "maxUserLevel": 1,
        "subsystems": [
            {
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "name": "test",
                        "allowedUsers": [
                            {
                                "user": {
                                    "username": "jack-94"
                                },
                                "permissions": [
                                    {
                                        "action": "get",
                                        "access": true
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "user": {
                                    "username": "john_65"
                                },
                                "permissions": [
                                    {
                                        "action": "get",
                                        "access": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "test2",
                        "allowedUsers": [
                            {
                                "user": {
                                    "username": "mery"
                                },
                                "permissions": [
                                    {
                                        "action": "put",
                                        "access": true
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "user": {
                                    "username": "amino"
                                },
                                "permissions": [
                                    {
                                        "action": "put",
                                        "access": false
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "test"
            }
        ],
        "name": "test",
    }
]
```

I'm looking for some way that set conditions on **section.allowedUsers.user.username** , as an example I want just to get sections with **section.allowedUser.user.username='jack-94'**

I try:

```
 path: "subsystems",
        populate: {
    path: "sections",
        populate: {
        path: "allowedUsers.user",
            model: "User",
            select: "username -_id",
    },
    match: {
        'user.username': 'jack-94'
    },
},
```

Also, I try:

```
    match: {
        ['allowedUsers.user.username']: 'jack-94'
    },
```

But not works...

Is there a way to do this with **mongoose** populate match conditions?

Thanks for any idea...